# Is the correct maximum runtime for this digit-removing algorithm O(1) or O(n)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o

I have written a small algorithm, that a changes a digit of a given number to zero. This is done in base 10. And the digits are indexed from least significant to most significant positions.

Example

```
unsigned int num = 1234
removeDigit(0, &num);  //  num == 1230
```

```
void removeDigit(unsigned int digit, unsigned int *num) {
    unsigned int th = 1;
    for (; digit > 0; digit--) th *= 10;
    while (*num / th % 10 != 0) *num -= th;
}
```

I was thinking about the runtime of the algorithm. I'm pretty sure its "technically" O(1), but I also see why you could say it is O(n).

The fact that an integer cannot have more than 11 digits, effectively makes it O(1), but you could still argue that for an arbitrary data type with an endless amount of digits, this algorithm is O(n).

What would you say? If someone were to ask me what the runtime of this is, what should I say?

Comment: This question is kind of subject to opinion.  You might be better asking this on another Stack Exchange site, one dedicated to _code reviews_.

Comment: @MickyD This would not belong on CodeReview.

Comment: @MickyD How is this "subject to opinion"?

Comment: What is your definition of n here?

Comment: @eozd Considering that no matter how large *num is, the amount of operations on it would not exceed 10, i define n as the "digit" index.

Comment: Also, you have code that works and are asking people to possibly **improve** it, that just makes your question arguably _too broad_

Comment: @MickyD No, he is explicitly **not** asking that.

Comment: @TomasWilson When n is the digit index to remove, the runtime of the algorithm directly depends on n. So, claiming that the runtime is O(1), hence independent of n, would be incorrect in my opinion. Yes, it is true that you will do at most 10 operations, but this doesn't imply that runtime is independent of n.

Comment: if n is the size of "num", you're going to perform at most n-1 multiplications to get final value of "th" and at most 9 subtractions to update num. hence complexity is O (n-1 + 9) = O (n)

Comment: Big O notation describes algorithms and not implementations and you have to analyze the behavior for `n` -> infinity. So it is O(n).

Comment: Why would you worry about the asymptotic complexity in `n` if your `n` is bound by 10?

Comment: My hard drive is bound by 1 TB. Why would I worry about asymptotic complexity of a search algorithm if it's bound. So every search algorithm would be O(1) because there can't be more data as 1 TB and more search steps as need to search this data.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Thank you! This is what I was unsure about.

Comment: @TomasWilson I hope you recognise the *irony* in the comment you are replying to.

Comment: The complexity of the algorithm and the complexity of this implementation of it are different because this implementation has a size limitation and algorithmic complexity is, by definition, for unbounded sizes.

Answer (score 2):

> What would you say? If someone were to ask me what the runtime of this is, what should I say?

When you give some time/space asymptotic bounds, typically it is because the algorithm can be used on arbitrarily large inputs.

In this case, your possible inputs are so constrained that providing the *absolute* maximum number of given operations/cycles/time that will take place worst-case can be a much more useful metric instead, in some domains.

Also consider that, given this is a very simple algorithm, you could simply provide the exact equations for the number of given operations/cycles/time, too; which is way more precise than giving either asymptotic bounds or absolute maximums.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is executed `digit+1` times. The while loop is executed `nd` times, where `nd` denotes the value of the designated digit. So in total generality, the asymptotic complexity is

```
O(digit + nd).
```

This formula is valid for any number length and any numeration base, but assumes that the arithmetic operations are done in constant time, which is somewhat unrealistic.

In any base, it is clear that `nd = O(1)`, as this number is bounded by the base. So *in the worst case*,

```
O(digit).
```

Now for fixed-length arithmetic, `digits` is bounded so that `digits = O(1)`. And as a consequence, the worst-case complexity is also

```
O(1).
```

---

Note that there is no incompatibility between the complexity being `O(digits + nd)` and the worst-case complexity being `O(1)`. This is justified by `digits` and `nb` both being `O(1)`.

Comment: If you're gonna be pedantic, you should consider that the C++ language spec does not actually specify a maximum for the size of an `int` ;)

Comment: @MattTimmermans: did I ever mention C++ or any programming language ?

Answer (score 0):

Other answers and comments have missed the fact that `removeDigit(1000000000,p)` will do a billion iterations of the first loop...  So this is certainly not O(1).   Sometimes in this kind of analysis we make use of the fact that machine words are of constant size, but asymptotic analysis ceases to be useful when we treat the largest possible integer value as a constant.

So...  unless otherwise specified, the *N* in *O(N)* or similar refers to the size of the input.  The size of an integer *x* would usually be considered to be *log<sub>2</sub> x* when it matters, so in terms of that usual convention, your function takes *O(2<sup>n</sup>)* time, i.e., exponential.

But when we use asymptotic analysis in real life we try to convey *useful information* when we make a statement of complexity.  In this case the most useful thing you can say is that `removeDigit(digit,p)` takes *O(digit)* time.